# Naive Bayes, Text Analysis, SKLearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, naivebayes

This is from a text analysis exercise using data from Rotten Tomatoes. The data is in critics.csv, imported as a pandas DataFrame, "critics".

This piece of the exercise is to

> Construct the cumulative distribution of document frequencies (df).
>   The   -axis is a document count  ()  and the   -axis is the
>   percentage of words that appear less than  ()  times. For example,
>   at  =5 , plot a point representing the percentage or number of words
>   that appear in 5 or fewer documents.

From a previous exercise, I have a "Bag of Words"

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

vectorizer = CountVectorizer()

# build the vocabulary and transform to a "bag of words"
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(critics.quote)

# Convert matrix to Compressed Sparse Column (CSC) format
X = X.tocsc()
```

Evey sample I've found calculates a matrix of documents per word from that "bag of words" matrix in this way:

```
docs_per_word = X.sum(axis=0)
```

I buy that this works; I've looked at the result.

But I'm confused about what's actually happening and why it works, what is being summed, and how I might have been able to figure out how to do this without needing to look up what other people did.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out last night. It doesn't actually work; I misinterpreted the result. (I thought it was working because Jupyter notebooks only show a few values in a large array. But, examined more closely, the array values were too big. The max value in the array was larger than the number of 'documents'!)

X (my "bag of words) is a word frequency vector. Summing over X provides information on how often each word occurs within the corpus of documents. But the instructions as for how many documents a word appears in (e.g. between 0 and 4 for four documents), not how many times it appears in the set of those documents (0 - n for four documents).

I need to convert X to a boolean matrix. (Now I just have to figure out how to do this. ;-)